# C++ Random Number Generation Using Mersenne Twister

Tags: c++, c++11, random, c++03, mersenne-twister

I'm trying to generate random numbers in my C++ program. It works on my laptop which runs windows. However, when I attempt to compile my program on another computer I get the following error messages:

```
error: ‘mt19937_64’ was not declared in this scope
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘randomGenerator’
```

corresponding the the following piece of code:

```
double** Euler::startSimulation(void) {

    mt19937_64 randomGenerator (mySeed);

/* More unshown code below... */

}
```

I am compiling my code from command line using g++ with the -std=c++0x flag. How do I fix this problem so my code can compile and run properly on both computers.

Comment: Are both computers 64 bit?

Comment: yes, both computers are 64 bit however, on my laptop I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 whereas I'm compiling at command line on my other machine, which runs linux

Comment: What is your GCC version? (`gcc - v`) Better use 'std=C++11', not '-std=c++0x'. -and- Try to add `-m64` flag to GCC. -or- Check if `std::mt19937` version works. -and- Try to resolve namespace explicitly: `std::mt19937_64` instead of 'mt19937_64'.

Comment: std::mt19937 works perfectly, but the other suggestions do not. When I type gcc -v I get: Target: x86_64-redhat-linux, gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC)

Comment: GCC 4.4 is a bit old. Not sure if it has implemented all C++11 features properly (but I don't know it exactly). Consider upgrade (`sudo yum install gcc-4.8.1 glibc* libstd*`). AFAIK, 4.8.1 is a first version which completely C++11 (and lastest stable for this moment). And +1 for using RedHat =)

Comment: Also, `std::mt19937` and `std::mt19937_64`is just `typedefs` for template specifications of [std::mersenne_twister_engine<>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine). You can try make same `typedefs` manually (or yours, custom ones).

Answer (score 2):

mt19937(_64) are both calssified in *namespace std*.

To make them available, you need to tell the compiler, where to look for them. Use either `std::mt19937_64 RdmGeneratorObject(seed);` ore give `using namespace std;` directive accordingly before opening the function declaration or main.